# *Edited* Aligning image and its caption when the image has a max-width

Tags: css, image

I have a fixed-width div with a image and caption of variable dimensions. 
Now the img has `max-width=100%` to prevent scaling beyond original size.
So, how do i format that caption so that it doesnt have a width larger than the image, hopefully without using js?

The problem comes when the img is small so that actually it could have a width greater than its original size, but due to max-width it gets constrained. The text below it doesnt get constrained because it cant know about the max-width of the image.

Edit: Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/bendtherules/L4Erc/ I want the text to be the same width as the image shown and directly below it.

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
    <p>
        This is a caption bigger than image
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper img{
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
p{
    border: 1px dashed;
}
```

Comment: Step 1: Show code or example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, using `display:table-caption;` it seems possible.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Erc/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="outter-wrapper">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
        <p>
            This is a caption bigger than image
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outter-wrapper{
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px dashed;
}
.inner-wrapper{
    display:table;
    border: 1px dashed;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner-wrapper img{
    background-color: green;
    max-width: 100%;
}
p{
    border: 1px dashed;
    display:table-caption;
    caption-side:bottom;
}
```

Comment: But I dont know the size of the image. I want to use it for image of any size without knowing the width beforehand.

Comment: Then you'll have to use Javascript, there's no other way.

Comment: Thats what I thought, thanks for clearing it. Can you help me with the js code?

Comment: Actually, I think I got it work... See my edited code and demo above.

Comment: Wow, it really works. Great work, i never really thought of using display:table for this.

Comment: This may have some browser compatibility quirks though... but it should work on all modern browsers.

Comment: does a display:table-caption have any restriction compared to display:block i.e. something I can do with the later but not the previous one?